# How to convert a CVS project to a SVN project in Netbeans

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, cvs

So, I have a project that I checkout from a SVN repo. However, once the project is in Netbeans, it is treated as a CVS project, because whoever put the project in the SVN repo forgot to convert it so it's full of CVS files. Is there a way to tell Netbeans to ignore this and treat the project as a SVN project?

Comment: What about checking out the project with a SVN client outside Netbeans, then remove all unnecessary CVS files, commit that change, and then start work in Netbeans for this project?

Comment: hmm that could work! I'll give it a try. Could you recommend a SVN client I should use?